# Compare two HashMaps with the Java streams API and replace attributes values in one HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-stream

I have 2 hashmaps

```
HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> deltaHashmap 

HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap
```

DedupeTableEntity has an id, country, entity_flag as attributes

- I want to iterate through the values of delta hash map (both hashmaps
  has only 1 key and list of values under that key)
- Check whether that object is in existing hash map if 2 attributes
  match (country and id)
- If it exists
- Take attribute value of (entity flag) that object from
  existinghashmap and replace the attribute (entity flag) value of the
  same object in the delta hash map

  ```
  public void compareTwoHashmaps(HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> deltaHashmap 
  , HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap){
          //iterate through deltahashmap values
          return deltaHashmap.values().stream()
                  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                  .filter(c -> (existingHashmap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(e->e.getId().equals(c.getId()) && e.getObjectCountry().equals(c.getObjectCountry())))
                          .map(k-> k.setEntityFlag(existingHashmap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(e->e.getId().equals(k.getId()) && e.getObjectCountry().equals(k.getObjectCountry())).map(r ->r.getEntityFlag()).toString()));
      }
  ```

this is what i have got so far. but there is an error which i dunno how to correct

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you required to use Streams for this?

Comment: yes I am @VGR . is there a better way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Performing a linear scan through `existingHashmap` for every element in `deltaHashmap` is extremely wasteful.
- `map` is not for *performing an action* on each element in a Stream.  `map` is for changing the element returned in a Stream.  For performing an action, you should use [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)).
- Calling toString() on a Stream is unlikely to produce useful information.

I would first map the values of `existingHashMap` by the properties used for matching.  An easy way to implement a compound key is by defining a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10) class.  This mapping by matchable properties allows quicker searching for matches without having to check every value of existingHashmap for every value in deltaHashmap.  (Record classes automatically define equals, hashCode, and toString methods based on their members.)

`map` should not be used here, because it returns a value—but there is no value to return.  You are setting a property in an entity.  Doing so does not return anything.

```
public void compareTwoHashmaps(
    HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> deltaHashmap,
    HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap) {

    record Identifiers(String id, String country) {
        static Identifiers of(DedupeTableEntity entity) {
            return new Identifiers(entity.getId(),
                                   entity.getObjectCountry());
        }
    }

    Map<Identifiers, DedupeTableEntity> allExisting =
        existingHashmap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Identifiers::of, e -> e));

    deltaHashmap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .forEach(delta -> {
            DedupeTableEntity existing =
                allExisting.get(Identifiers.of(delta));

            if (existing != null) {
                delta.setEntityFlag(existing.getEntityFlag());
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though there were some incorrect parenthesis in the stream. There was also some possible duplicate code, which I tried to reduce. I also made a few extractions and ended up with this:

```
public void updateFlag(
        Map<DedupeTableEntity, List<DedupeTableEntity>> deltaHashmap,
        Map<DedupeTableEntity, List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap
) {
    deltaHashmap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .forEach(k -> extractFlag(existingHashmap, k)
                    .ifPresent(k::setEntityFlag));
}

private Optional<String> extractFlag(Map<DedupeTableEntity, List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap, DedupeTableEntity k) {
    return existingHashmap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(e -> equalsByIdAndCountry(k, e))
            .findFirst().map(DedupeTableEntity::getEntityFlag);
}

private boolean equalsByIdAndCountry(DedupeTableEntity c, DedupeTableEntity e) {
    return e.getId().equals(c.getId()) && e.getObjectCountry().equals(c.getObjectCountry());
}
```

I don't have any data to test if it's actually correct, so I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contained some errors:

- The method has a return type of void, but it attempts to return a stream.
- The call to map on the filter operation is not terminal, meaning that it won't actually execute the mapping operation.
- To fix these issues, the method could be modified to return the modified deltaHashmap

a fixed version including a return statement:

```
public HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> compareTwoHashmaps(
    HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> deltaHashmap,
    HashMap<DedupeTableEntity,List<DedupeTableEntity>> existingHashmap) {
deltaHashmap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(c -> existingHashmap.values().stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .anyMatch(e -> e.getId().equals(c.getId()) && e.getObjectCountry().equals(c.getObjectCountry())))
        .forEach(k -> {
            Optional<String> entityFlag = existingHashmap.values().stream()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .filter(e -> e.getId().equals(k.getId()) && e.getObjectCountry().equals(k.getObjectCountry()))
                    .map(r -> r.getEntityFlag())
                    .findFirst();
            entityFlag.ifPresent(k::setEntityFlag);
        });
return deltaHashmap;
}
```